# Downloading Enterprise WSDL in Chrome

Tags: wsdl

With Chrome on Windows it's very difficult for me to actually download the generated WSDL (so I can save it to my Visual Studio project). Save As and View Page Source then Save As leaves the injected xml decorations in the final file. Attempting a Save As on the link for the Generate button returns html. The generation url is protected so switching to another tool at that point is painful too.

I want to get a plain xml document saved to my local drive as easily as possible. With Firefox I can do a Save As in the browser and get a clean file out of it. Does anyone have any tricks to make this work in Chrome on Windows? Is there an idea already lobbying Salesforce to set the headers so the file always downloads (or another idea that would help this problem)?

Comment: I've also had this experience, with Opera and Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try right clicking the page and click "View page source".  The Source **IS** the XML document

Comment: I knew and tried the View Page Source trick. Now I've realized that where I went wrong was trying to save straight to a .wsdl extension. That's when Chrome injects a ton of html. If I save to a .xml extension it works just fine and I can rename it to a .wsdl after that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Not ideal, but this trick does work for me. In Chrome, pull up developer tools and go to the Network tab before you click the Generate button. Click the wsdl.jsp item and copy out of the Response tab. Start highlighting at the first character and then Ctrl+Shift+End. I diffed and this method avoided all of chrome's html decorations.

[image: Wsdl From Network Response]

Answer (score 1):

There is another way for download your organization-specific WSDL

> `https://[SERVER_INSTANCE].salesforce.com/soap/wsdl.jsp?type=*`

SERVER_INSTANCE = with Server Instance,