# Cannot see wsdl download link

Tags: wsdl

I am using PHP Toolkit to get objects data.
But I am unable to get custom objects data. Through some research I came to know that I have update my wsdl file.
So as instructed I followed the following path

```
Setup >> Develop >> API
```

But couldn't find any link to download the wsdl file.
The only link I saw was

```
http://developer.salesforce.com
```

I am using unlimited edition as a site administrator.
Is wsdl download link only available for enterprise edition?

And if not then why I am unable to see or get any download link for wsdl file?

Comment: you can try

http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22214/downloading-enterprise-wsdl-in-chrome/83312#83312

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WSDL is available on any edition that has the API enabled: Enterprise, Unlimited, Performance, Developer, and Sandbox (and a few other special types). If you don't have the link to the WSDL, it is likely you do not have permission for that organization. Often times, some administrators will make so-called "admin" profiles that are not actually administrators. This is the most likely scenario in your case. Check your user profile and make sure you have Customize Application and Modify All Data. This is what qualifies a user as an admin. Failing that, it's possible your org is not configured correctly. I would ask the user that set you up to review your profile or contact technical support.